# How to see if columns contain nulls and count them if they have in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(1) - COUNT(NAME) as Name,
    COUNT(1) - COUNT(SURNAME) as Surname,
    COUNT(1) - COUNT(AGE) as Age 
FROM
    Employees
```

That's my code to count the number of nulls the columns have. But I want to count only columns which have nulls. How do I do that?

Comment: . . A SQL query returns a fixed set of columns.  If you want a variable set, you need to use dynamic SQL.  Example results would make your question clearer -- and you should tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Or do you want to count the number of null names and the number of null surnames and the number of null ages?  You could say SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE NAME IS NULL , but I don't know how you'd do that for all three columns in one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might want something like:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Name FROM Employees;
```

This will produce the number of Employees that have `NULL` for the `Name` column - but without filtering them out of the overall query, so you can add other aggregates for the other columns. Repeat the `SUM` and `CASE` bit as needed for other columns.